# Error : OnEditorActionListener() is not working (tried every solution i can find)

Tags: android, xml, retrofit

So when i click the enter button on keyboard it should return me all the data from elastic search server but when i click the button nothing happens. I thnk OnEditorActionListener() is not working  And the log is also not showing in the logcat. I tried every solution on other question but it either changes my enter button to search button or does nothing. Can anyone tell me whats wrong in the code and how can i fix it.

this the whole code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;  
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import ankittx.com.forsale.models.HitsList;
import ankittx.com.forsale.models.HitsObject;
import ankittx.com.forsale.models.Post;
import ankittx.com.forsale.util.ElasticSearchAPI;
import ankittx.com.forsale.util.PostListAdapter;
import okhttp3.Credentials;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "SearchFragment";
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://35.184.51.77//elasticsearch/posts/post/";

//widgets
private ImageView mFilters;
private EditText mSearchText;

//vars
private String mElasticSearchPassword;
private String mPrefCity;
private String mPrefStateProv;
private String mPrefCountry;
private ArrayList<Post> mPosts;
private String searchString = " ";


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    mFilters = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ic_search);
    mSearchText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.input_search);

    init();
    getElasticSearchPassword();

    return view;
}

private void init(){
    mFilters.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to filters activity.");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FiltersActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onEditorAction: onEditorAction is working ");
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                    ||actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                mPosts = new ArrayList<Post>();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                ElasticSearchAPI searchAPI = retrofit.create(ElasticSearchAPI.class);

                HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headerMap.put("Authorization", Credentials.basic("user", mElasticSearchPassword));

                if(!mSearchText.equals("")){
                    searchString = searchString + mSearchText.getText().toString() + "*";
                }
                if(!mPrefCity.equals("")){
                    searchString = searchString + " city:" + mPrefCity;
                }
                if(!mPrefStateProv.equals("")){
                    searchString = searchString + " state_province:" + mPrefStateProv;
                }
                if(!mPrefCountry.equals("")){
                    searchString = searchString + " country:" + mPrefCountry;
                }

                Call<HitsObject> call = searchAPI.search(headerMap, "AND", searchString);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<HitsObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<HitsObject> call, Response<HitsObject> response) {

                        HitsList hitsList = new HitsList();
                        String jsonResponse = "";

                        try{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: server response: " + response.toString());

                            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                                hitsList = response.body().getHits();
                            }else{
                                jsonResponse = response.errorBody().string();
                            }

                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: hits: " + hitsList);

                            for(int i = 0; i < hitsList.getPostIndex().size(); i++){
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: data: " + hitsList.getPostIndex().get(i).getPost().toString());
                                mPosts.add(hitsList.getPostIndex().get(i).getPost());
                            }

                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: size: " + mPosts.size());
                            //setup the list of posts

                        }catch (NullPointerException e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
                        }
                        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage() );
                        }
                        catch (IOException e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<HitsObject> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage() );
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "search failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getFilters();
}

private void getElasticSearchPassword(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getElasticSearchPassword: retrieving elasticsearch password.");

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(getString(R.string.node_elasticsearch))
            .orderByValue();

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot singleSnapshot = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
            mElasticSearchPassword = singleSnapshot.getValue().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void getFilters(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mPrefCity = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.preferences_city), "");
    mPrefStateProv = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.preferences_state_province), "");
    mPrefCountry = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.preferences_country), "");

    Log.d(TAG, "getFilters: got filters: \ncity: " + mPrefCity + "\nState/Prov: " + mPrefStateProv
            + "\nCountry: " + mPrefCountry);
}
```

}

XML code =

```
  <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_border_bottom"
    android:padding="2dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="search..."
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ic_search"
            android:id="@+id/input_search"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/ic_search"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_toolbar"
    android:background="@color/lightGrey">


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:visibility="gone">

</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How is the EditText (`input_search`) defined in `xml`? Please provide that too

Comment: @Alex i have added the xml code. I tried adding android:inputType="text"  but it does not working

Comment: When i added it changed enter button to checkbutton and when i click it the button it showed the log but then it showed errors.

Comment: Yes, you need to add `android:inputType="text"` (as you did), to make the editorActionListener work. The checkbutton it shows can be changed with using the `android:imeOptions` option if you like.

Comment: It shows the log, so that's working now. What errors does it show after clicking the button? That must be caused by the logic inside the listener